# Quotation Marks VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a function that inputs a formula into a cell. But I keep on receiving a syntax error. I know this is due to the quotation marks. I was wondering how I would go about including the quotation marks of the formula in the function without causing a syntax error.

Any help would be grateful.

```
Sub codedump()


      Range("A1").Value = "=Dump(GoogleAnalytics("ga:78770227", "ga:visits", "2014-05-28", "2014-06-26", "","", "", "", 500, FALSE, FALSE))"

End Sub
```

Comment: Escape it with two double quotes. So a string with a quotation mark would look like `""""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use escaping

For example, `""` gives a quotation mark. Otherwise, use char codes

```
Sub codedump()

      Range("A1").Value = "=Dump(GoogleAnalytics(""ga:78770227"", ""ga:visits"", ""2014-05-28"", ""2014-06-26"", """","""", """", """", 500, FALSE, FALSE))"

End Sub
```

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k4fw5(v=vs.85).aspx

Alternatives:

```
'Escaping
Private Sub InsertQuote()
   TextBox1.Text = "She said, ""You deserve a treat!"" "
End Sub

'Character code
Private Sub InsertAscii()
   TextBox1.Text = "She said, " & Chr(34) & "You deserve a treat!" & Chr(34)
End Sub

'Defined string
Const quote As String = """"
TextBox1.Text = "She said, " & quote & "You deserve a treat!" & quote
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wrap your quotation marks in quotation marks to get them to appear on the sheet.  Something like:

```
Range("A1").Value = "=Dump(GoogleAnalytics(""ga:78770227"", ""ga:visits"", ""2014-05-28"", ""2014-06-26"", """","""", """", """", 500, FALSE, FALSE))"
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 Chr(34) & Chr(34)
```

in place of

```
 ""
```

34 is the ASCII character code for " and VBA will convert Chr(34) to " when it builds your string.

Comment: VBA uses Unicode so ASCII character codes are not relevant. Of course, by design, Unicode is a superset of ASCII and uses the same character codes for the common characters.

Comment: Good to know. I usually just use the ASCII list because it's smaller and I don't need much other than what is in it. Thanks.