# how to use variable containing strings in formula vba

Tags: vba, excel

I ask the user input for a string and then need to incorporate this into a formula. I searched on other questions but didn’t get the desired output.

```
Sname = InputBox("Enter name")

Cells(2, 32).FormulaR1C1 = _
=CONCATENATE(J2,""-"",K2,""-"",L2,""-"" "" & Sname & "" -"",T2,U2,V2,W2,X2,Y2,""-"",AB2,""-"",AC2)
```

suppose i enter AAA
i want the formula on cell(2,32) to be

```
=CONCATENATE(J2,"-",K2,"-",L2,"-" & "AAA" & "-",T2,U2,V2,W2,X2,Y2,"-",AB2,"-",AC2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quotation Marks VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454575/quotation-marks-vba)

Comment: @vacip I do have the double quotation mark? or is it that I'm not getting something?

single quotation marks appear in the cell after i run the macro as well

` =CONCATENATE('J2', " - ", 'K2', " - ", 'L2', " - ", "&Sname&", " - ", 'T2', 'U2', 'V2', 'W2', 'X2', 'Y2', " - ", 'AB2', " - ", 'AC2') `

is what the cell displays after i run the module. the name of the variable is being displayed as well "Sname" it wanted it to display what i entered

Comment: @vacip that did slove part of the froblem but as i said in my comment on sythr's reply i cant get the Sname variable value into the formula

Comment: Ah, ok. Wrong flag then... It is not duplicate, but a simple typographical error. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cells(2,32).Formula = _
 "=CONCATENATE(J2,""-"",K2,""-"",L2,""-"" & """ & Sname & """ & ""-"",T2,U2,V2,W2,X2,Y2,""-"",AB2,""-"",AC2)"
```

There was a slight mixup with your quotation marks around the variable.

This one works for me.

Comment: `=CONCATENATE(J2,"-",K2,"-",L2,"-" & " Sname " & "-",T2,U2,V2,W2,X2,Y2,"-",AB2,"-",AC2)` this is what appears on the cell as the formula.

`Sname = InputBox("Enter name")` would be specified by the user and if suppose they enter AAA i want the forumla in the cell to be 

`=CONCATENATE(J2,"-",K2,"-",L2,"-" & "AAA " & "-",T2,U2,V2,W2,X2,Y2,"-",AB2,"-",AC2)`

Comment: My bad. Edited. Quotation marks can get you mixed up. :)

Comment: thankyou so much ^_^ ive just been learning VB for a few weeks no wonder if its confusing to someone as good as you i had a hard time.

Answer (score 0):

swap " for ' **Tip**: you can use CTRL+U

```
=CONCATENATE(J2,'-',K2,'-',L2,'-' & 'AAA' & '-',T2,U2,V2,W2,X2,Y2,'-',AB2,'-',AC2)
```

Add a replace function

```
Replace("=CONCATENATE(J2,'-',K2,'-',L2,'-' & 'AAA' & '-',T2,U2,V2,W2,X2,Y2,'-',AB2,'-',AC2)","'", Chr(34))
```

Chr(34) equal to caracter "